# Transpose row-columns and Counting number of instances per column in SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table structured as

```
|creationDate|rule.      |position| 
|01.01.2018  |squid:S1132|12      |
|01.01.2018  |squid:S1132|14      |
|01.01.2018  |squid:S1132|19      |
|01.01.2018  |squid:S1121|12      |
|01.01.2018  |squid:S1121|14      |
|01.02.2018  |squid:S1130|12      |
```

My goal is to count the number of rules per date, reporting them in different columns.

```
|creationDate| S1132      | S1121 | S1130 |
|01.01.2018  | 3          |2      | 0     |
|01.02.2018  | 0          |0      | 1     |
```

I have a total of 180 rules...
Is it possible to make it in a single query?

Running this query

```
select creationDate , count("creationDate") as "squid:S1132" 
from SONAR_ISSUES 
where rule='squid:S1132' group by creationDate
```

I obtain this result

```
|creationDate|S1132  | 
|01.01.2018  |3      |
```

I can do a similar query for each rule, but then, I am not able to merge them...

Comment: Do you really want to do a pivot with 180 columns per row, or can you work with a bunch of `(date, rule, count)` rows or the results returned as, say, a json object? Either would be a lot easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by using case when

```
select creationDate ,count(case when rule='squid:S1132' then 1 end) as S1132,
count(case when rule='squid:S1121' then 1 end) as S1121,
count(case when rule='squid:S1130' then 1 end) as S1130    
from SONAR_ISSUES 
group by 
creationDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using conditional aggregation

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=b59b959a71cca25399169c9a6069a233)

```
select 
   creationDate, 
   count(case when rule='squid:S1132' then "creationDate" end) as "squid:S1132",
   count(case when rule='squid:S1121' then "creationDate" end) as "squid:S1121" ,
   count(case when rule='squid:S1130' then "creationDate" end) as "squid:S1130" 
from SONAR_ISSUES 
group by creationDate
```